# What is the difference between .col-xs-4 or col-xs-4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

New to HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. Is it necessary to add a period before col-xs-4? What is the difference between .col-xs-4 and col-xs-4?

I currently have this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class=".col-xs-4">
  <h1 class="#">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `dot` in `.col-xs-4` is used while defining css classes, while `col-xs-4` is used without `.` when adding them as css reference on `html` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the period.
The dot is used in the CSS to specify it as a class.

```
.col-xs-4 {
width: 25%;
}
```

Then the class is added to the element in the HTML. The dot isn't needed because it is in the class attribute.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting a `.` before `col-xs-4` in the class attribute of the element. The `.` is the character used to indicate that whatever follows it until the start of the next selector segment is a class.

Similarly, you do not want to put a `#` character in the ID field.

Reference: [W3 Schools CSS Selectors Page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)